# Outer Space Flamethrower

Tags: technology, space, physics, weapons, chemistry

I know from [here](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=1006041614112) that a flame thrower can operate in deep space if specially built. However, I want to know if using a flamethrower on a spaceship in space could have any tactical benefits. Could a flamethrower be used to destroy or blind enemy sensors from several kilometers away, or would it burn out? Would it be possible to build a flamethrower that can reach targets several kilometers away in space?

Comment: Why would you want this? Are standard particle weapons not good for everyone anymore?

Comment: @AngelPray Some prefer a less technological approach

Comment: I think the answer sufficiently point out why it's a bad idea as a ship-to-ship weapon.  Conversely, it's an ideal weapon for a boarding party, imo, as borne out by a number of movies and games.

Comment: @AngelPray Not so fast! Haven't you seen the "Alien" movie? They didn't have no flashy particle thingy. But they knew all creatures abhor fire!

Comment: @Paul No, actually it's a terrible idea for a boarding party unless the boarders don't need to breathe and are immune to fire, as borne out by the safety manual for every submarine ever made.  Fire is pretty much the *worst* thing that can happen in a giant sealed metal can full of pressurized air.

Comment: @RBarryYoung It would work if the defenders depressurized the ship to slow down the attackers, and make them easier to eliminate.

Comment: @Hyperdriveenthusiast In what sense would killing everyone on the ship by depressurizing it, be making a flamethrower "work"?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Everyone would preferably be wearing spacesuits. This would be done, so the defenders could take out the attackers in a single direct hit, which could tear the suit.

Comment: Why would you assume that everyone on a ship had a space suit?  Submarines don't have diving suits for every crewmember. Further, a flamethrower in vacuum still isn't a good weapon whether it's inside or outside the ship.  The purpose of a flamethrower is to make other things burn, but in a vacuum, they'll stop burning as soon as the oxidant runs out. Now a cutting torch would be handy, but that's not a flamethrower.

Comment: I assume that most spacecraft will have a spacesuit for each crewman. I think that it a hull breach on a spaceship is more likely than one on a submarine and having a spacesuit probably helps your survival chances more than having a diving suit on a submarine with a hull breach.I think that having a flamethrower is about as useful as having a gun when boarding a depressurized spaceship. It also has a big psychological effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54419/discussion-between-hyperdrive-enthusiast-and-rbarryyoung).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Nope

#### Improper Usage

Remember that the **purpose of a flamethrower is to set flammable targets on fire** like wood structures and humans and to consume oxygen from enclosed spaces.  It is safe to assume that spaceships will not be made out of flammable materials.  Ships are sealed so that they do not lose oxygen to space, so unless the flamethrower can penetrate the hull it will not harm the air inside the ship.  There are also far more effective methods to blind enemy sensors than generating a lot of heat and IR.  Space ships already are going to be able to filter out far hotter things from their sensors like near by stars.

#### Distance and Velocity

For a flame thrower to travel one kilometer it would need to ignite at the end of the stream on impact otherwise it will burn its fuel off before it got to the target.

Flamethrowers also run into an issue that the fluid is not going to be moving that fast compared to other weapons so enemies will easily see it coming and avoid it.  You can switch it out for an incendiary missile, which will get the payload to its target faster, but it will cease to be a flamethrower at that point.

#### Armor and Shields

Space ships are going to be designed to handle far worse than what a flamethrower can dish out.  Flamethrowers are a chemical based weapon and so they generate energy through chemical reaction.  However, there are a large number of weapons out there that can generate far more destructive forms of energy, and as such space ship defenses will be designed to handle those types of things.  So when the flamethrower hits the shields or armor at the worst it will likely only damage the paint job.

Comment: +1 for this post, but I will mention that another tactical use of Flamethrowers was to consume the Oxygen in fortifications.

Comment: And any craft capable of atmospheric flight will be explicitly designed to handle worse temperature. The only use I can imagine is if for some reason nanodust swarm clouds become weaponrised. Then flamethrowers would be a good point defence against them. Keep in mind that in vacuum such swarm couldn't manoeuvre so it would have to be released by ships, hoping enemy can't detect it until too late, or as payload by missile. Flamethrowers would provide good last line of defence when it's already too late to dodge.

Comment: @Sarriesfan yes I forgot that one, I will add it to the list.

Comment: This. I think what he's looking for are plasma based weapon systems. Fire in space just doesn't make sense. The OP also seem to be unaware that space combat will take place at more than just _many miles away_. In the void you could potentially engage enemies at thousands if not hundred-thousand miles away. When you will get close enough to use fire you are already dead.

Comment: Fire in space makes sense if you have an oxidizer. You can find ways to increase flamethrower range to a few kilometers, and somehow find a way to ignite the stream of fuel and oxidizer. You could even just put fuel and oxidizer in shells and fire them.

Comment: @Miech It is one thing to deal with hot plasma rushing past you.... it is another thing entirely to deal with some sticky stuff that clings to your ship and that is making the hull itself combust. :D

Comment: @Hyperdriveenthusiast I am not sure that actually is possible, mind you. Fuel/oxidiser mixes are volatile. That's how internal combustion engine works. Materials which don't need external oxidisers, like gunpowder, nitrocellulose, nitroglycerine, TNT or C4 tend to either explode or deflagrate violently. While technically fire is deflagration, materials which contain oxidiser or don't need oxidiser deflagrate at very fast rate, too fast to be practical in flamethrower. Important feature of atmospheric fire is limited access to oxygen, this slows process and makes it last much longer.

Comment: @Miech I believe these problems could be overcome with the right fuel and oxidize. Perhaps I should ask a question about the best fuel and oxidizer for a vacuum operating flamethrower

Answer (score 20):

Why would you do this?
Usually space weapons are high energy high velocity.

There's benefit to utterly unexpected tactics.
Flamethrower won't work for practical reasons, but how about some super caustic thermite goo?

"Sir, incoming"
"Missile?"
"Nope, too slow, no evidence of a guidance system"
"Impact danger?"
"Low mass and velocity, no danger of hull breeach"
"Hold course, ready main missile batteries, energy weapons and rail guns."
"Ready... wait, hull sensors in the area of impact are starting to go down"
"Damage control teams to affected decks. What is it?"
"It's goo, wait, now it's on fire, hull breech warning on decks three and seven, also four. Now five and six."
"Fire control teams, seal all decks prepare for depressurization"

Bam. Goo wins the day.

Comment: The advantage of thermite being that it does neither require nor produce any gases, just juicy white-hot iron.

Comment: For this to be an effective tactic, you'll probably want to send out a whole lot of projectiles, with most of them being just cheap light empty decoy shells, so it's impractical for the target ship to just destroy all of them from afar to be safe.

Comment: So... they can detect an incoming projectile ... and they just shrug it off because they _think_ it's not insanely hot? How did they detect it and not notice the temperature?

Comment: What @JanDvorak said. A gentle nudge with maneuvering thrusters would most likely be all you need to move out of the projectile's path, particularly if it is unguided; *not* doing so would be the bad choice, even if you *think* the risk is small. Let alone that a small projectile could also pack quite a punch. Also, keep in mind that velocity is a relative quantity. Remember: Action should generally be proportional to risk (of impact, say) multiplied by potential effect (you're in a combat situation, so it's reasonable to expect anything incoming to be potentially capable of doing harm).

Comment: I was going to reply with something like this. You can't shoot fire in space, but you can shoot something like "fire ingredients" that will activate when in contact with the ship's material and atmosphere.

Comment: @ecc Hypergolics do just fine, if you can get a sufficiently energetic reaction. Just make the containers such that the parts mix on contact with the target but not before then.

Comment: "Why would you do this? Usually space weapons are...". And there is the answer to your question: because this is an **unusual** space weapon. Just imagine the complete shock on the faces on the command bridge. "Uhm... captain... we have a problem?" "What?" "We.... are on fire". "There is a fine in the ship?!" "No... the ship itself is on fire". "Great Scott!" "Yeah, this is heavy..."

Answer (score 9):

A flamethrower is, fundamentally, a device that ejects burning-hot stuff at a moderate-to-fast speed.

A rocket is a device that ejects stuff at *very* fast speeds, and the stuff it ejects tends to be burning-hot (since that's a very effective way to make fast-moving exhaust).

If for some reason a spaceship builder decided to put a flamethrower on the outside of their ship, especially if it needs a range of several kilometers, it seems likely that it would be based on a backwards-facing rocket more than a traditional earthbound flamethrower. What you'd be looking at there would be [weaponized exhaust](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WeaponizedExhaust) - along with some (possibly rather significant) acceleration away from the target.

Comment: Or just use the actual rocket engine on your ship: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WeaponizedExhaust

Comment: Yep, pretty much. I figured I'd avoid a TVTropes link, but I can edit that in if you think it would improve the answer.

Comment: TVTropes links are more often helpful than not on this site, since tropes are a major part of worldbuilding.

Answer (score 4):

What you're essentially looking for is something that's fuel and oxidizer. White Phosporous's probably the good stuff. Add an oxidiser since space dosen't typically have an atmosphere, and something thick and sticky to carry it all and stick to surfaces, since there's no gravity in space. Maybe encapsulate the two chemicals so they don't react prematurely in heat-decomposing "cells". Since its space, lauching it as a stream makes no sense. Instead have them in canisters with an igniter that kickstarts the combustion. Launch them have them hit and splash on a target - vaguely like a HESH round *then* sets the fuel, which is stuck to the target on fire

Since space craft have limited capacity to dump out heat, this might actually end up being *pretty* nasty. It would be a complicated/rube goldbergian weapon though

You could also use them as decoys or flares as needed. However, I do suspect something like this wouldn't be as effective in most cases as big, dumb, fast projectiles, except against say a space station or other stationary target.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a flamethrower inside as spaceship to devastating effect if a flamethrower is specifically what you want. However, if you want to attach a flamethrower to a spaceship that would not be the most effective use of a flamethrower or a spaceship. If you absolutely need to use a flamethrower in space consider drones. Drones can reach high velocities and hit enemy ships super far away. Then you might get some practical use. Particle cannons, missiles, and railguns are still probably more effective, though... I hope that was helpful!